# How to use distinct clause only for one column

Tags: sql

I wanted to use distinct clause only for one column.I am having query like this
`select id,brandname from brand.`
Here brandname have same entry multiple time.I wanted to choose distinct brandname along with id.

Answer (score 1):

You have to pick some way of getting only one ID, e.g.,

```
select max(id) , brandname 
from brand
group by brandname
```

if you had more than one column you wanted... if the data was the same you could just continue to group by... however if extra columns had varying data you could use a slightly different strategy.

```
select * from brand 
where id in 
(
    select max(id)
    from brand
    group by brandname
)
```

Comment: Hi jsobo,thanks for ur reply.According to this,it is working properly.But this is the right way?

Comment: Yes this is the right way to do it. Fortunately you are only retrieving two columns, if you go beyond it may not work

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
select Id,BrandName from brand group by BrandName,Id
```